# Rails query executes 2 queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading

I have a simple rails query like

```
a = A.where(type: 'user')
if a.count > 1
  #Log Information
end
return a
```

Rails does lazy loading where it doesn't query the database unless some operation on the result set is executed. This is a fine behavior. But in my case rails ends up executing 2 queries because I call `a.count` before operating on `a`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `a` WHERE `a`.`type` = 'user';
SELECT  `a`.* FROM `a` WHERE `a`.`type` = 'user';
```

Is there any way I can ask rails to perform the query immediately so that only the second query is executed and the count is returned from the dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the results into an array. I think that `to_a` will work for that, but `entries` is a clearer way express that intention since its job is to iterate over the items in an `Enumerable` and return an array of the enumerated results.

```
a = A.where(type: 'user').entries
if a.count > 1
  #Log Information
end
return a
```

Comment: write a word or two on what is entries. never heard before. +1

Comment: I was trying to post an answer quickly, and then fill it out. :)